# Youtube API - Problems uploading a video

Tags: php, youtube-api, google-api-php-client

I'm using google/google-api-php-client version 1.1.6. Then I'm using `resumable_upload` to upload video to youtube (sample code https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/php/resumable_upload.php) And I got this problem when trying to upload new video to youtube with message (view my attached):

```
'Failed to start the resumable upload (HTTP 500: global, Backend Error)'
Stack trace:
#0 Google_Http_MediaFileUpload->getResumeUri()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 500s can happen sometimes with the YouTube API. Did you re-try the request? This is Google's recommended action.

Comment: Hi @Joe, I will go ahead to re-try the request when catch this problem. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: No problem. Retrying works for me, have only had a handful of times where it fails twice, and that's making thousands of requests a day.